# django rest framework fails to serialize foreignkey field from string value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to submit post data to an api endpoint, which should create a model instance and return the object back in the response.

And here is the returned error message.

```
IntegrityError at /api/messages/
null value in column "sender_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (27, null, null, this is a test message, warning: this is a test. this is only a test. please disregard. ..., f, null, f, f).
```

Those first two `null` fields should be the sender and receiver, which I assume aren't being serialized properly.

The post request body looks like this. `sender` and `receiver` are foreign key fields.

```
{
    "sender": "user1",
    "receiver": "user2",
    "subject": "this is a test message",
    "body": "warning: this is a test. this is only a test. please disregard. say hello to your mother for me.",
    "read": false,
    "sender_deleted": false,
    "receiver_deleted": false
}
```

Here are my model and view.

```py
class MessageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
     sender = serializers.StringRelatedField()
     receiver = serializers.StringRelatedField()

     class Meta:
         model = Message
         fields = ['pk', 'sender', 'receiver', 'subject', 'body', 'read', 'sender_deleted', 'receiver_deleted']

 class Message(models.Model):
     sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sent_mail')
     receiver= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='received_mail')
     subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
     body = models.TextField()
     read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     sender_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     receiver_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     replies = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='parent_message')

     def __str__(self):
         return self.subject
```

The serializer fails to associate the provided username with the user object. How do I fix this?

Comment: from the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) StringRelatedField `This field is read only.`

Comment: Thanks. I changed the StringRelatedFields to SlugRelatedFields and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the StringRelatedFields, which are write only, to SlugRelatedFields.

```py
 class MessageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
     sender = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', queryset=User.objects.all())
     receiver = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', queryset=User.objects.all())
      class Meta:
         model = Message
         fields = ['pk', 'sender', 'receiver', 'subject', 'body', 'sender_read', 'receiver_read', 'sender_deleted', 'receiver_deleted']
```